# Styling Active Link Within Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, selecteditem

I wish to style the current selected link in CSS / JS with a different colour to inactive links.

I found this code which i inserted into my page

```
.current_page_item a.active {color: blue;}
```

which i believe is a class within the current selected item, however it seems to have failed.

Site is : http://www.milknhny.co.uk/ShopTest

Would this be doable with js?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had this answered, because i have it within a specific DIV i had to declare this first so this is the correct code:

```
#menuwrap ul li.current-menu-item a
```

Thankyou for your help though.